# How to call stored procedure with out parameters in Intellij Idea?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, intellij-idea, db2

Basically what I want to do is call a stored procedure with out parameters (DB2), unfortunately intellij interprets the question marks as user parameters.

I tried adding an exception for *?* in *Settings->Database->User parameters*, but this didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to disable User parameters at all in that settings? What do you get when trying to execute it? How do you expect the query should be executed?

Comment: Yes I tried disabling them altogether. I even tried adding an exception for DB2 \? pattern, but idea nevertheless prompts me to insert the parameters. I always get that 'no stored procedure found with such arguments' which is valid because it has out parameters and I specified a specific value not a placeholder to fill.

Comment: Disabling user parameters should work. What's the sql text? What Is IDE version?

Comment: I'm calling it like this: CALL MY_STORED_PROC(?); and intellij just prompts me for parameters. I tried disabling the user parameters but literally nothing changes. I'm using the 2017.3 Ultimate edition. What I think from this site (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/user-parameters.html) is that the ? is treated as a default user parameter and you can only define additional patterns to be user parameters in the settings

Comment: Thank you for details. I've created the issue, please follow the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5865

Comment: could you clarify on [this question](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5865#comment=27-2700877) please?